# Recycler View Items in a fragment overlaps after device resumes from sleep

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I've a fragment in an activity which displays some items using recycler view, items appear fine when they're first loaded but **when the device goes to sleep and resumed after sometime, items are overlapped over previous item list**.

When recycler is first loaded it appears fine:

[image]

But when the device goes to sleep after inactivity and resumes, I can see that recycler view has 2 lists(copies) one at the background and one at foreground! It's evident when you scroll!

[image]

MY fragment class is :

```
public class TablesFragment extends Fragment implements AsyncTaskCompleteListener<String> {

RecyclerView mTablesRecyclerView;
Context mContext;
ConnectivityManager mConnManager;
TableListAdapter mTableListAdapter;
TakeAwayOrderAdapter mTakeAwayListAdapter;
public static List<Table> mTableList;
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tables_pane_layout,container,false);
    mTablesRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.tablesListRecycler);
    mContext = getActivity();
    String urlString="http://"+MainActivity.IP_ADDRESS+"/Central_Webapp/TablesServlet";

    ServerCalls serverCalls = new ServerCalls(mContext,TablesActivity.mProgressBar,this);
    serverCalls.execute(urlString,"GET");

    return view;
}


@Override
public void onTaskComplete(String result) {
     if(isAdded())
     {
         if(result==null||result.isEmpty())
         {
             return;
         }
         try {

             JSONArray jsonArray =new JSONArray(result);

                 mTableList = TableParser.getTableListFromJSONArray(jsonArray);
                 clearOrderPreferences(mTableList);
                 Table t = new Table();
                 t.setTableName(SharedStrings.addNew);
                 mTableList.add(t);
                 mTableListAdapter = new TableListAdapter(mTableList,this,mContext);
                 mTablesRecyclerView.setAdapter(mTableListAdapter);

             mTablesRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(mContext));
         } catch (JSONException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
     }

}

}
```

fragment xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/tablesListRecycler"
        ></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Recycler item XML:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tableListItemLayoutID"
    android:padding="10dp"
   >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tableNameTextID"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="TextView"
           android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tableCapacityTextID"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:gravity="bottom|right"
            />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: show your adapter XML file

Comment: Can you please tell us more about the overlapping? The idea is not that clear.

Comment: @AbhinavGupta added the xmls

Comment: @ReazMurshed I've added extra info, may be it's clear now! Basically when the device resumes from sleep. fragment displays recycler in which one list is in background and is fixed, there is one more list which is in foreground and is scrollable! You can see 2 separate lists when you scroll

Comment: Thank you. Now the problem is clear.

Comment: Any suggestions ?